# How to get coordinates of words and elements from a PDF using java

Tags: java, pdf

We need to parse some pdf files and add some numbers or text on it at certain positions and then save them. Currently we use a tool 'Foxit PDF Editor' to get the x-y coordinates for each element. This is a GUI based software that you click the element on the pdf then the x-y coordinates will be displayed in the properties window. Is there anyway to get the coordinates programmatically using java? Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Raistlin

Comment: HAve you considered itext?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am searching any kind of java library that can do this. I will try itext. Thanks

Comment: There is a whole list of possibilities [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java).

Comment: What kinds of elements are of interest for you? What kind of licenses are ok in the context of your project? If commercial is ok, how much money are you prepared to spend?